# Unable to install Helix example for Asp.Net Core - MsBuild timeout out while trying to get project to project references

Tags: jss, docker

I'm trying to setup the helix example for asp.net core rendering following this [article](https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples/tree/master/examples/helix-basic-aspnetcore).

It's not going past step 12 and shows this error.

```
MsBuild timeout out while trying to get project to project references.
The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; nuget restore -Verbosity
quiet' returned a non-zero code: 1   
ERROR: Service 'solution' failed to
build : Build failed
```

[image]

I have also added `"dns":["8.8.8.8"]` to the Docker Engine configuration.

Comment: Can you verify that you are running windows containers?

Comment: @SumitUpadhyay Could you pls let me know how?

Comment: The easiest method would be to right-click on Docker Desktop in the tray icon. You should see "Switch to Windows Containers" which means that you are running Linux containers. Once you click this, try re-running the setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems Symantec was causing the problem. I have stopped it by executing `smc -stop` in the Run dialog.

Comment: This solved the issue for me too, thank you!